# ¿Cómo resuelvo el error implicit declaration of function?[C]

Tags: c

estoy haciendo mi primera aplicación en C y no encuentro la forma de resolver estos errores:

> implicit declaration of function 'tolower' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
> passing argument 1 of 'tolower' makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
> passing argument 1 of 'strcmp' makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]

Este es el código:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "iniciarSesion.h" 
#include "crearSesion.h"

int main(void) {

    int option;
    char selection[2];
    //Primer menú repetitivo
    while(option!=3) {
        printf("\t\t!Bienvenido!\n");
        printf("1. Iniciar sesion.\n2. Crear sesion.\n3. Borrar datos/n4. Salir\n");
        printf("Escoja una opcion: ");
        scanf("%i", &option);
        
        switch(option) {
            case 3: 
                system("cls");
                printf("\n¿Desea eliminar sus datos?\nEsta accion es permanente (si/no)");//Elimina todos los datos de las sesiones creadas, no hay vuelta atrás
                scanf("%s", selection);

                    if(strcmp(tolower(selection), "si") == 0) {
                        remove("saveData.txt");
                        printf("Los datos han sido eliminados exitosamente.\n");                    
                    }
                
                system("pause");
                system("cls");
                system("exit");
            break;
```

Lo que no entiendo es a que se refiere con "makes pointer from integer without a cast", ¿Cómo podría hacer eso?.
¿Esta podría ser la razón de que cuando compilo el programa el cmd no imprime nada ni me permite cerrarlo?
Gracias...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vamos a ver los problemas que tiene esta línea:

```
char selection[2];
if(strcmp(islower(selection), "si") == 0) { // <<---
```

Para ello vamos a empezar viendo la firma de la función `islower`:

```
int islower (int c);
```

Ya podemos ver el primer problema:

La función `islower` recibe un entero, tu código le está pasando un array. Los arrays decaen a punteros, de ahí el texto del mensaje de error:

> passing argument 1 of 'islower' makes integer from pointer without a cast

Que viene a decir que el argumento 1 de `islower` está haciendo una conversión de puntero a entero

Viendo tu código entiendo que tu aquí no pretendías llamar a `islower` sino a `tolower`:

- `islower` te devuelve un 1 o un 0 en función de si el caracter que se le pasa está en minúsculas o no
- `tolower` convierte un caracter a minúsculas

El problema ahora es que, efectivamente, `tolower` no recibe un array o un puntero sino, nuevamente, un entero. Si quieres pasar una cadena a minúsculas es necesario recorrer esa cadena a mano para ir convirtiendo todos sus caracteres:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < strlen(selection); ++i)
{
    selection[i] = tolower(selection[i]);
}
```

Tras esta operación ya puedes llamar a `strcmp` para comprobar si el texto introducido por el usuario coincide con `si`:

```
if (strcmp(selection, "si") == 0) {
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya voy a corregirlo